# How can I set up jQuery.swap to have zoom 0 in body element for google chrome

Tags: jquery

Google Chrome for some reason add zoom:1.01 in my body element I think it is from `jQuery.swap`
can I set up to be 0 for chrome.

```
<body class="home blog class-name" style="zoom: 1.01;" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
```